# Yiii2 subdomain in url manager not working

Tags: php, routes, yii2, url-routing, yii-url-manager

I have a Yii2 advanced project. I have MyCompanyController.php in the frontend controllers and I want to add a subdomain to this controller so I did this :

```
    'urlManager' => [
        'rules' => [
            '/' => 'site/index',
            'http://co.example.com' => 'my-company/index', // Not work :-(
            'http://co.example.com/<action>' => 'my-company/<action>',
             ...
        ]
     ]
```

Now this code is working perfectly and when I open http://co.example.com/index my index action gets rendered, But when I open http://co.example.com without mentioning the action it is not working and it calls the site controller's index action instead .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is the order of the url rules.

I suspect the application is called with another URL like http://example.com or http://bla.example.com or what is the `/` rule for?

As it seems `/` is sufficient for any URL that has no path component, so second rule doesn't get evaluated. You could either prepend the protocol and domain path like `'http://example.com/' => 'site/index'` (so the other (suspected) domain is explicitly declared and this rule won't match if http://co.example.com is called) or just remove this rule (if *site/index* shouldn't be called at all).

Note that if no rule matches the [defaultRoute](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-applications.html#defaultRoute) of the application will be used.

From the [Yii2 Guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#url-rules):

> ... to parse an incoming request, the URL manager examines the rules in
>   the order they are declared and looks for the first rule that matches
>   the requested URL.
>
> [...]
>
> When parsing or creating URLs, URL manager examines URL rules in the
>   order they are declared. Therefore, you may consider adjusting the
>   order of the URL rules so that more specific and/or more commonly used
>   rules are placed before less used ones.

See also the Yii2 Guide about [Rules with Server Names](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html#rules-with-server-names).